# Replace origins latest commit with locals latest

Tags: git

I have one commit in the origin repo that i havent pulled and i dont want to. I want to push my latest local commit to origin instead.

```
gitHub/origin
        "commit nr 10"
```

localRepo
          "also commit nr 10, behind one commit"

Is there anyway i can replace the commit nr 10 in origin with my latest in local without having to pull the latest?

If i do

```
git pull
```

creates a merge conflict and then i have to resolve it for every file using mine.

Is there a way i can pull and always use mine for conflicts or delete the latest commit in the origin so that i can push my local commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "force" push your branch to the remote. That is, `git push origin <branch-name> --force`. This will essentially force the remote branch to mimic your local branch, which will rewrite the history of the remote branch. Note that re-writing history is considered incredibly bad practice, as one of the main components of git is to be distributed. If anybody pulled the remote branch, then you force push to that branch, they'll now have conflicts the next time they try to sync with the remote.

Comment: That will do it! Im the only one in this project so no problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should merge your code to your `origin repo` or you have to take pull first then and only then you can `commit and push your changed` files to the `origin repo`.

If you want to push your code then you need to create a new branch and push your code into that branch.

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name master-branch-name
```

If you don't want to commit then checkout your code by `git checkout -b file-name`

If you have added your changed file and you want to reset your files then

```
git reset --hard origin/some-branch
```